# NGINX block access to folder not working

Tags: nginx

I would like to block access to a specific folder.

```
www.example.com/user/login

Here is my nginx vhost:

server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.php;


        server_name example.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/admin/(.*)?$ /admin/index.php?a=$1 break;
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?a=$1 last;
                break;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~ "/index.(php|html?)") {
                rewrite ^ /$1 permanent;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }


        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|woff)$ {
                expires 365d;
        }


location /user/login {
deny all;
        }


        location ~ (\.sql.gz|\.sql) { return 403; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
#               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}

server {
        listen 80;

        server_name  www.example.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

I still have access to that folder. (yes I made  `nginx -s reload` and restart nginx after each try).

Instead of:

```
location /user/login {
deny all;
        }
```

I tried also the following directives:

```
location = /user/login {
deny all;
        }

location ^~ /user/login {
deny all;
        }
```

But none of them is blocking access to that folder.

Can anyone help to spot the problem?

Comment: what is the complete url you want to block?

Comment: http://example.com/user/login

Answer (score 1):

Replace this block

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/admin/(.*)?$ /admin/index.php?a=$1 break;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?a=$1 last;
    break;
}
```

and this block

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

with

```
location ~ /(?<path>.*)$ {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?a=$path;
}

location ~ /admin/(?<path>.*)$ {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?a=$path;
}
```

`try_files` is the nginx native way to implement front controller pattern. These two `location` blocks perform the same function as `rewrite` statements in the `if` block.

Furthermore, they solve the issue you are having, because nginx usual `location` matching order is not disturbed by the `if` condition.

Comment: After this change you suggested the `location = /user/login` directive works well. But something stopped working. Now all subpages give a 404. For example example.com/blog example.com/contact etc

Comment: OK, I see that your front-controller expects the part after `/` in the URL path component. That is a bad requirement, makes many complications in many places. Anyway, I updated my answer to extract the path after leading `/` and pass it to `index.php` `a` argument.

Comment: You can test it. Now when I go to the homepage downloads the php file. Here is the live site http://glmr.in/ and all other subpages give still 404

Comment: I rearranged the `try_files` statements, hope it works better now.

Comment: done, it now keeps downloading php files for every page, even for pages that do not exist. If it may help, here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/ZMrN6q7n

Comment: Did you have a chance to take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following part of your nginx config:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/admin/(.*)?$ /admin/index.php?a=$1 break;
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?a=$1 last;
                break;
}
```

Because this condition is true when you are accessing `example.com/user/login` your nginx is entering the statement inside the if block and not the statements inside `location /user/login`

So in order to resolve your issue remove this if statement completely or put it inside another location block.